# Prove there is no natural number $n$ such that $n$ is $2,5,6$ or $8$ times by the power of its units digit.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

One of my friend showed me yesterday this 5th grade problem.

For me the incoherence and the language is a bit strange, but I do believe that with your help we can manage to demonstrate this:

> Show that there isn't a natural number which increased $2,5,6$ or $8$ times by the power of its first digit at the end of the number.

Comment: The natural number $2$ has first (and last) digit $2$, and it is increased $2$ times when raised to the power of $2$:

$$ 2^2 = 2\cdot 2$$

Comment: So basically we found out that the statement is false? This problem was given at a math contest. Sorry for my English, but I do really translated  this word by word

Comment: I find the language impossible to interprete.  I honestly have no idea whatsoever what "by the power of its first digit at the end of the number" means.  So if you have number $253$ and the first digit is $3$.  So $2*3=6$.  So we raise it to the sixth power.  $253^6 = 262254607552729$ and .... now what?  What is supposed to be impossible about that?

Comment: Are you trying to say that $253$ does not equal $2^3; 5^3;6^3;$ or $8^3$?  Or that $253^3$ does not equal $2*253$ or $5*253$ or $6*253$ etc. or what?

Comment: @FlorinM. Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can consider for $x_i=\{0,1,...,9\}$

$$N=10^n x_n+...+10x_1+x_0$$

$$N^{x_0}-N=kN\implies N^{x_0-1}-1=k\implies N^{x_0-1}=k+1$$

then

- $x_0=1\implies k=0$
- $x_0=2\implies k=1,11,...$
- $x_0=3\implies k=8,168,...$
- $x_0=4\implies k=64,2743,...$
- $x_0=5\implies k=624,...$
- $x_0=6\implies k=7775,...$
- ...

Comment: 'k' being how many times we multiplied the number?

Comment: @FlorinM. Yes k if the multiplication factor. I've intepreted the OP as $N^{x_0}-N=kN$ for the increment but do not obtain the given answer. We could consider $N^{x_0}=kN$ but also in this case the result would be different.

Comment: Sorry my later question(s) but why you decrease that N from N^x0 ?

Comment: @FlorinM. From the statement of the OP it seems that the increase should be evaluated as difference between $N^{x_0}$ and $N$. If what you mean if different you should clarify that.

Comment: @FlorinM. Anyway we can also apply the same method to $N^{x_0}=kN\implies N^{x_0-1}=k$